# Google Maps HTML in markers

Tags: php, html, google-maps

I am trying to insert html into InfoWindows. I have managed to set up the map and get text (including html formatting) into the InfoWindows. The code is as follows

```
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
  var customLabel = {
    restaurant: {
      label: 'R'
    },
    bar: {
      label: 'B'
    }
  };

    function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.5, -3.04),
      zoom: 10
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
      downloadUrl('genxml2.php', function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
          var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
          var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
          var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

          var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
          var strong = document.createElement('strong');
          strong.textContent = name
          infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
          infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

          var text = document.createElement('text');
          text.textContent = address
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            label: icon.label
          });
          marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        });
      });
    }



  function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
      }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
  }

  function doNothing() {}
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDHIP7rWh6XQFCO_dPIVnW3TXMZ4fiRtSY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

The problem is the InfoWindows are dispalying the html markup.
[The sample page is here](http://walkingbritain.co.uk/maps/map.php)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the browser to render the HTML markup in the InfoWindow, you have to pass it in as a string, not a HTML DOM node.

```
var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: point,
  label: icon.label
});
marker.addListener('mouseover', (function(infowindowContent){
  return function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  }}(name)));
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/y3ya4qov/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var customLabel = {
  restaurant: {
    label: 'R'
  },
  bar: {
    label: 'B'
  }
};

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.5, -3.04),
    zoom: 10
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
  // downloadUrl('genxml2.php', function(data) {
  // var xml = data.responseXML;
  var xml = parseXml(xmlStr);
  var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
    var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
    var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
    var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
      parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
      parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

    var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: point,
      label: icon.label
    });
    marker.addListener('mouseover', (function(infowindowContent) {
      return function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    }(name)));
  });
  // });
}



function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
    new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}

function parseXml(str) {
  if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    doc.loadXML(str);
    return doc;
  } else if (window.DOMParser) {
    return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
var xmlStr = '<?xml version="1.0"?><markers><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-3508-introduction target=blank&gt;The Crinkle Crags from Wrynose Pass&lt;/a&gt; (5.00 miles)" lat="54.414586" lng="-3.1155786"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-3525-introduction target=blank&gt;Catbells from Gutherscale (Route B)&lt;/a&gt; (4.00 miles)" lat="54.57946" lng="-3.1680418"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1214-introduction target=blank&gt;Carrock Fell &amp; High Pike from Mosedale&lt;/a&gt; (7.00 miles)" lat="54.69416" lng="-3.0053205"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1214-introduction target=blank&gt;Carrock Fell &amp; High Pike from Mosedale&lt;/a&gt; (7.00 miles)&lt;br&gt;&lt;a href=/walk-1101-introduction target=blank&gt;Carrock Fell, High Pike and Knott from Mosedale&lt;/a&gt; (11.00 miles)" lat="54.69416" lng="-3.0053205"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-3234-introduction target=blank&gt;Gummers How via Chapel House Wood, South Lake District&lt;/a&gt; (5.50 miles)" lat="54.28037" lng="-2.9399236"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-3470-introduction target=blank&gt;Blencathra via Foule Crag from Scales&lt;/a&gt; (8.00 miles)" lat="54.631094" lng="-3.0239026"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-3388-introduction target=blank&gt;Around Hayeswater and Angle Tarn From Hartsop&lt;/a&gt; (11.50 miles)" lat="54.51236" lng="-2.9251636"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-3328-introduction target=blank&gt;Eagle Crag &amp; Seargeant&amp;apos;s Crag from Stonethwaite&lt;/a&gt; (7.00 miles)" lat="54.513207" lng="-3.1414353"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-3037-introduction target=blank&gt;High Seat &amp; Bleaberry Fell from Keswick&lt;/a&gt; (9.00 miles)" lat="54.595015" lng="-3.1390793"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-3034-introduction target=blank&gt;Red Screes &amp; Other Fells from Ambleside&lt;/a&gt; (10.00 miles)" lat="54.443002" lng="-2.9451871"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1011-introduction target=blank&gt;Knott Rigg and Ard Crags from Newlands Hause&lt;/a&gt; (3.50 miles)" lat="54.547179" lng="-3.2506017"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1302-introduction target=blank&gt;Low Fell and Fellbarrow from Loweswater&lt;/a&gt; (6.00 miles)" lat="54.582951" lng="-3.3507276"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-3309-introduction target=blank&gt;Hartsop, Hartsop Dodd, Stony Cove Pike &amp; Kirkstone Pass&lt;/a&gt; (8.50 miles)" lat="54.508848" lng="-2.9142728"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1023-introduction target=blank&gt;Wansfell Pike &amp; Wansfell from Ambleside&lt;/a&gt; (7.50 miles)" lat="54.432061" lng="-2.9649759"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1565-introduction target=blank&gt;Rydal Water &amp; Grasmere from Grasmere village&lt;/a&gt; (6.00 miles)" lat="54.455866" lng="-3.0210657"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1565-introduction target=blank&gt;Rydal Water &amp; Grasmere from Grasmere village&lt;/a&gt; (6.00 miles)&lt;br&gt;&lt;a href=/walk-1472-introduction target=blank&gt;Alcock Tarn, Rydal Water &amp; Grasmere from Grasmere&lt;/a&gt; (7.00 miles)" lat="54.455866" lng="-3.0210657"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-3697-introduction target=blank&gt;Loughrigg Fell from Skelwith Bridge&lt;/a&gt; (4.50 miles)" lat="54.421773" lng="-3.0140529"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-3199-introduction target=blank&gt;Whitbarrow Fell from Mill Side&lt;/a&gt; (7.00 miles)" lat="54.248735" lng="-2.8425154"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2675-introduction target=blank&gt;Eel Tarn and Stony Tarn from Eskdale&lt;/a&gt; (6.00 miles)" lat="54.397275" lng="-3.2321733"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2355-introduction target=blank&gt;Blea Tarn &amp; Eskdale Green from Boot&lt;/a&gt; (6.50 miles)" lat="54.394115" lng="-3.276745"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1676-introduction target=blank&gt;Ullock Pike, Long Side and Carl Side&lt;/a&gt; (5.50 miles)" lat="54.668259" lng="-3.1860949"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-3033-introduction target=blank&gt;Tarn Crag &amp; Harrop Pike from Sadgill, Longsleddale&lt;/a&gt; (5.50 miles)" lat="54.44406" lng="-2.7987183"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-3029-introduction target=blank&gt;Walla Crag from Keswick&lt;/a&gt; (6.50 miles)" lat="54.595015" lng="-3.1390793"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2582-introduction target=blank&gt;Pike o&amp;apos; Stickle, Harrison Stickle &amp; Pavey Ark&lt;/a&gt; (6.00 miles)" lat="54.428331" lng="-3.086664"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2581-introduction target=blank&gt;Lord&amp;apos;s Seat &amp; Barf from Whinlatter&lt;/a&gt; (8.50 miles)" lat="54.609395" lng="-3.2308322"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2539-introduction target=blank&gt;Rannerdale Knotts &amp; Grasmoor&lt;/a&gt; (8.00 miles)" lat="54.552996" lng="-3.2956197"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2526-introduction target=blank&gt;Standing Crag, Ullscarf &amp; Borrowdale&lt;/a&gt; (10.00 miles)" lat="54.536771" lng="-3.120455"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2526-introduction target=blank&gt;Standing Crag, Ullscarf &amp; Borrowdale&lt;/a&gt; (10.00 miles)&lt;br&gt;&lt;a href=/walk-2525-introduction target=blank&gt;Standing Crag &amp; Dock Tarn from Watendlath&lt;/a&gt; (7.00 miles)" lat="54.536771" lng="-3.120455"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2524-introduction target=blank&gt;Thirlmere Circular&lt;/a&gt; (5.00 miles)" lat="54.567006" lng="-3.0563227"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2425-introduction target=blank&gt;Circuit of Boredale from Patterdale&lt;/a&gt; (11.50 miles)" lat="54.53474" lng="-2.936488"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2362-introduction target=blank&gt;Scafell Pike and Scafell from Eskdale&lt;/a&gt; (11.00 miles)" lat="54.397275" lng="-3.2321733"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2362-introduction target=blank&gt;Scafell Pike and Scafell from Eskdale&lt;/a&gt; (11.00 miles)&lt;br&gt;&lt;a href=/walk-2361-introduction target=blank&gt;Walking on Water to Scafell from Eskdale&lt;/a&gt; (9.50 miles)" lat="54.397275" lng="-3.2321733"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2585-introduction target=blank&gt;Hartsop Dodd, Stony Cove Pike, High St. &amp; The Knott&lt;/a&gt; (10.00 miles)" lat="54.508859" lng="-2.9127286"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2587-introduction target=blank&gt;Castlerigg Stone Circle &amp; St John&amp;apos;s in the Vale&lt;/a&gt; (8.50 miles)" lat="54.590767" lng="-3.1126513"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2932-introduction target=blank&gt;A Green Burn horseshoe from Mill Bridge, Grasmere&lt;/a&gt; (7.00 miles)" lat="54.472899" lng="-3.0261194"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2932-introduction target=blank&gt;A Green Burn horseshoe from Mill Bridge, Grasmere&lt;/a&gt; (7.00 miles)&lt;br&gt;&lt;a href=/walk-2841-introduction target=blank&gt;Grisedale Tarn &amp; Seat Sandal from Mill Bridge, Grasmere&lt;/a&gt; (5.00 miles)" lat="54.472899" lng="-3.0261194"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2721-introduction target=blank&gt;Scout Scar Limestone Ridge&lt;/a&gt; (5.00 miles)" lat="54.293151" lng="-2.7865759"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2715-introduction target=blank&gt;Skelwith Bridge &amp; Loughrigg from Elterwater&lt;/a&gt; (5.50 miles)" lat="54.433257" lng="-3.0374614"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2652-introduction target=blank&gt;Photographer&amp;apos;s Kentmere Horseshoe&lt;/a&gt; (13.50 miles)" lat="54.428522" lng="-2.8369521"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2642-introduction target=blank&gt;Buttermere Horseshoe&lt;/a&gt; (14.00 miles)" lat="54.539765" lng="-3.2720148"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2631-introduction target=blank&gt;A Martindale High-level Circuit&lt;/a&gt; (11.00 miles)" lat="54.563958" lng="-2.8752953"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2612-introduction target=blank&gt;Roughton Gill, Caldbeck Fells&lt;/a&gt; (4.50 miles)" lat="54.725851" lng="-3.0821892"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2609-introduction target=blank&gt;Crag Hill &amp; Grasmoor from Buttermere&lt;/a&gt; (8.00 miles)" lat="54.540582" lng="-3.2797689"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2341-introduction target=blank&gt;A circuit of Nether Beck and Over Beck from Wasdale&lt;/a&gt; (11.25 miles)" lat="54.449739" lng="-3.2861872"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2321-introduction target=blank&gt;Shores of Derwentwater from Keswick&#13;&#10;&lt;/a&gt; (3.50 miles)" lat="54.5950150" lng="-3.1390793"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-3232-introduction target=blank&gt;Glenridding Dodd &amp; Sheffield Pike from Glenridding&#13;&#10;&lt;/a&gt; (4.50 miles)" lat="54.5436180" lng="-2.9506035"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1668-introduction target=blank&gt;Silver Knott &amp; Muncaster Fell from Irton Road&#13;&#10;&lt;/a&gt; (5.00 miles)" lat="54.3872440" lng="-3.3304307"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1555-introduction target=blank&gt;Brunt Knott from Staveley&#13;&#10;&lt;/a&gt; (7.00 miles)" lat="54.374722" lng="-2.8189234"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1462-introduction target=blank&gt;Mardale Head horseshoe&lt;/a&gt; (8.00 miles)" lat="54.488834" lng="-2.8227468"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1463-introduction target=blank&gt;School Knott &amp; Grandsire from Ings&lt;/a&gt; (6.50 miles)" lat="54.38074479" lng="-2.857534658"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1082-introduction target=blank&gt;Ennerdale Horseshoe&lt;/a&gt; (18.00 miles)" lat="54.524222" lng="-3.3781454"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1059-introduction target=blank&gt;Colwith Force and Skelwith Force from Elterwater&lt;/a&gt; (4.80 miles)" lat="54.4332570" lng="-3.0374614"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1058-introduction target=blank&gt;Beacon Fell &amp; Beacon Tarn circular&lt;/a&gt; (4.00 miles)" lat="54.310538" lng="-3.0927798"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1049-introduction target=blank&gt;Staveley tarns circular&lt;/a&gt; (6.00 miles)" lat="54.375641" lng="-2.8158627"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1671-introduction target=blank&gt;Grike &amp; Crag Fell from Ennerdale Bridge&#13;&#10;&lt;/a&gt; (6.60 miles)" lat="54.5288930" lng="-3.4401157"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1823-introduction target=blank&gt;Fairfield Horseshoe &amp; Loughrigg from High Close&#13;&#10;&lt;/a&gt; (14.00 miles)" lat="54.4397050" lng="-3.0191217"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1932-introduction target=blank&gt;Slight Side from Whahouse Bridge&#13;&#10;&lt;/a&gt; (5.60 miles)" lat="54.3972750" lng="-3.2321733"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1693-introduction target=blank&gt;Grange &amp; Watendlath from Rosthwaite&#13;&#10;&lt;/a&gt; (7.60 miles)" lat="54.5230180" lng="-3.1494342"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1692-introduction target=blank&gt;Great End &amp; Glaramara from Seathwaite&lt;/a&gt; (7.70 miles)" lat="54.4984300" lng="-3.1827147"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1690-introduction target=blank&gt;Netherbeck Horseshoe - Middle Fell, Steeple &amp; Red Pike&lt;/a&gt; (12.50 miles)" lat="54.4497390" lng="-3.2861872"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1826-introduction target=blank&gt;Green Gable &amp; Gillercomb Horseshoe from Seathwaite&#13;&#10;&lt;/a&gt; (5.50 miles)" lat="54.4984300" lng="-3.1827147"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1684-introduction target=blank&gt;Lingmoor Fell &amp; Langdale from Elterwater&#13;&#10;&lt;/a&gt; (7.00 miles)" lat="54.4332570" lng="-3.0374614"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1682-introduction target=blank&gt;Rydal Water &amp; Grasmere from Grasmere&#13;&#10;&lt;/a&gt; (5.50 miles)" lat="54.4558660" lng="-3.0210657"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-3119-introduction target=blank&gt;Catbells, Dale Head &amp; Hindscarth - The Newlands Horseshoe &#13;&#10;&lt;/a&gt; (12.00 miles)" lat="54.5794600" lng="-3.1680418"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-3423-introduction target=blank&gt;Dove Crag &amp; Red Screes - Scandale Horseshoe&lt;/a&gt; (9.50 miles)" lat="54.4320610" lng="-2.9649759"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1045-introduction target=blank&gt;Levens Bridge to Kendal&lt;/a&gt; (11.50 miles)" lat="54.259971" lng="-2.775198"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1148-introduction target=blank&gt;Scout Scar from Sizergh&lt;/a&gt; (11.00 miles)" lat="54.276196" lng="-2.7678239"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2226-introduction target=blank&gt;The Scafells from Eskdale&lt;/a&gt; (12.00 miles)" lat="54.399243" lng="-3.2152879"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1417-introduction target=blank&gt;Astley&amp;apos;s Plantation, Simpson&amp;apos;s Ground &amp; Gummer&amp;apos;s How&lt;/a&gt; (7.50 miles)" lat="54.28037" lng="-2.9399236"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2718-introduction target=blank&gt;The Scafells from Wasdale Head&lt;/a&gt; (9.00 miles)" lat="54.465322" lng="-3.2573609"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2718-introduction target=blank&gt;The Scafells from Wasdale Head&lt;/a&gt; (9.00 miles)&lt;br&gt;&lt;a href=/walk-2900-introduction target=blank&gt;Pillar (by the High Level Path) from Wasdale&lt;/a&gt; (8.00 miles)" lat="54.465322" lng="-3.2573609"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2718-introduction target=blank&gt;The Scafells from Wasdale Head&lt;/a&gt; (9.00 miles)&lt;br&gt;&lt;a href=/walk-2900-introduction target=blank&gt;Pillar (by the High Level Path) from Wasdale&lt;/a&gt; (8.00 miles)&lt;br&gt;&lt;a href=/walk-2800-introduction target=blank&gt;The Scafells via Piers Gill&lt;/a&gt; (7.50 miles)" lat="54.465322" lng="-3.2573609"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1124-introduction target=blank&gt;Beacon Tarn &amp; The Beacon, near Torver&lt;/a&gt; (4.00 miles)" lat="54.309626" lng="-3.0942927"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-3410-introduction target=blank&gt;Latterbarrow from Hawkshead&lt;/a&gt; (4.00 miles)" lat="54.373378" lng="-2.9974657"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-3110-introduction target=blank&gt;The Old Man of Coniston &amp; Dow Crag from Torver&lt;/a&gt; (8.50 miles)" lat="54.344683" lng="-3.0936857"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-3220-introduction target=blank&gt;Wetherlam from Coniston by Red Dell&lt;/a&gt; (7.00 miles)" lat="54.368225" lng="-3.0743014"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2073-introduction target=blank&gt;Three of the Langdale peaks&lt;/a&gt; (8.25 miles)" lat="54.448099" lng="-3.0871875"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1916-introduction target=blank&gt;Harter Fell and Low Birker Tarn (Eskdale)&lt;/a&gt; (6.50 miles)" lat="54.399243" lng="-3.2152879"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1141-introduction target=blank&gt;An Elterwater circular&lt;/a&gt; (4.00 miles)" lat="54.4332570" lng="-3.0374614"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-3075-introduction target=blank&gt;Ambleside and Rydal circular &lt;/a&gt; (6.50 miles)" lat="54.432061" lng="-2.9649759"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1506-introduction target=blank&gt;Sharp Edge &amp; Blencathra from Scales&lt;/a&gt; (5.00 miles)" lat="54.631094" lng="-3.0239026"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2053-introduction target=blank&gt;Claife Heights from Near Sawrey&lt;/a&gt; (2.50 miles)" lat="54.352026" lng="-2.9707921"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-3519-introduction target=blank&gt;High Sweden Bridge from Ambleside&lt;/a&gt; (3.00 miles)" lat="54.432061" lng="-2.9649759"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-3419-introduction target=blank&gt;Scafell Pike from Brotherilkeld, an Eskdale circular&lt;/a&gt; (12.50 miles)" lat="54.399243" lng="-3.2152879"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-3320-introduction target=blank&gt;A Grizedale Tarn circular&lt;/a&gt; (2.50 miles)" lat="54.339912" lng="-3.0228037"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2229-introduction target=blank&gt;Tarns of Eskdale&lt;/a&gt; (7.50 miles)" lat="54.397275" lng="-3.2321733"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-2818-introduction target=blank&gt;Bowfell Circular&lt;/a&gt; (7.00 miles)" lat="54.444365" lng="-3.1025093"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-3028-introduction target=blank&gt;Tarn Hows &amp; Tom Gill from Coniston&lt;/a&gt; (6.50 miles)" lat="54.368225" lng="-3.0743014"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1245-introduction target=blank&gt;Castle Crag &amp; Grange from Seatoller&lt;/a&gt; (6.00 miles)" lat="54.512957" lng="-3.1676877"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1188-introduction target=blank&gt;Blencathra via Hall&amp;apos;s Fell ridge from Scales Farm&lt;/a&gt; (6.00 miles)" lat="54.631094" lng="-3.0239026"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1187-introduction target=blank&gt;Robinson &amp; Hindscarth from Newlands&lt;/a&gt; (6.50 miles)" lat="54.563975" lng="-3.1892514"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1177-introduction target=blank&gt;Great Sca Fell via Trusmadoor&lt;/a&gt; (6.50 miles)" lat="54.711833" lng="-3.1408"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1176-introduction target=blank&gt;Yewbarrow from Wasdale&lt;/a&gt; (4.50 miles)" lat="54.449739" lng="-3.2861872"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1175-introduction target=blank&gt;A Combe Gill circuit from Seatoller&lt;/a&gt; (5.50 miles)" lat="54.512132" lng="-3.1599409"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1171-introduction target=blank&gt;Pike o&amp;apos; Blisco from Blea Tarn, Langdale&lt;/a&gt; (5.00 miles)" lat="54.428331" lng="-3.086664"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1170-introduction target=blank&gt;A shortened version of the Fairfield Horseshoe&lt;/a&gt; (9.50 miles)" lat="54.432061" lng="-2.9649759"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1158-introduction target=blank&gt;High Rigg from Legburthwaite&lt;/a&gt; (5.50 miles)" lat="54.567006" lng="-3.0563227"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1157-introduction target=blank&gt;Bowfell and Esk Pike from Old Dungeon Ghyll&lt;/a&gt; (8.75 miles)" lat="54.444365" lng="-3.1025093"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1207-introduction target=blank&gt;Great &amp; Little Langdales&lt;/a&gt; (8.50 miles)" lat="54.448099" lng="-3.0871875"/><marker name="&lt;a href=/walk-1217-introduction target=blank&gt;Dow Crag &amp; the Old Man of Coniston&lt;/a&gt; (8.50 miles)" lat="54.368225" lng="-3.0743014"/></markers>'
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you for taking the time to provide an answer - your efforts are much appreciated

Comment: If this answered your question, please [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I see you have commented out these two lines   downloadUrl('genxml2.php', function(data) {
var xml = data.responseXML; can you keep these in working exmaple on my website?

Comment: Those were commented out so I could provide a proof of concept with your data (which is not available on other domains due to the cross domain restriction on XmlHttpRequest, except through a proxy), you shouldn't need to change that in your version.

Comment: i've basically copied and pasted your code. Deleted the var xmlstr and date and reinstated the two lines that were commented out. I get nothing ...?

Comment: Any javascript errors reported in the JavaScript console? Although the change is pretty small, you should be able to just modify your "working" code with event listener code from mine.

Comment: error on this line function downloadUrl(url, callback) {

Comment: You have to "uncomment out" the end of the downloadUrl function as well.  Did you do so?

Comment: I've uncommented end of downloadURL function - now map is loading but no markers or InfoWindows. New version is at The page is here www.walkingbritain.co.uk/maps/map.php

Comment: I see javascript errors: `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined`, `Uncaught ReferenceError: xmlStr is not defined`

Comment: Probably just remove the lines that generate those errors